# JPA and Lombok causing StackOverflowError in circular dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, lombok, circular-dependency

I have two entity classes:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, exclude = "products")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @ToString.Exclude
    private String password;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("remember_me")
    private Boolean rememberMe;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "tbl_user_role")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductEntity> products = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_product")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class ProductEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity user;
    private String productName;
}
```

both extending a baseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Version
    private long version;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        BaseEntity that = (BaseEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) && Objects.equals(version, that.version);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, version);
    }
}
```

Now when I try to retrieve all products (or all users) (e.g. `findAll` method) I get a `StackOverflowError`.
I know this error is caused by the circular dependency between user and products, so I added an exclude to the equals annotation in the userEntity to resolve it, like so:
 `@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, exclude = "products")`

Unfortunately the error keeps popping up. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that in general it's not a good idea to override `equals` and `hashCode` for entities. The specific characteristic that distinguishes entities from values is that entities have an identity independent of their data.

Answer (score 2):

In case it might help, lombok also has anotation `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` very useful for tests!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by adding `@ToString.Exclude` to the `roles` and `user` class variables. Apparently I was printing them somewhere later in the code, which was causing the error.